# Why is my variable undefined on init in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, service, init

I initialize services on my component like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getValue1();
    this.getValue2();
    this.getValue3();
}
```

and when services have got data i want to do that:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getValue1();
    this.getValue2();
    this.getValue3();
    this.result = this.value1.view_count.value + this.value2.view_count.value + this.value3.view_count.value;

}
```

but i got that :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'view_count' of undefined

How can i wait services result do to my operation?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

```
getvalue1(): void {
    this.subscription=this.dataService.getViews(360001167865).subscribe(data => {
        this.value1 = data;
    });
}
```

service.ts:

```
 getViews(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL + "views/" + id + "/count.json", { headers: headers });
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more info I thnk. Can you add the code for the `getValue1` function please? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: Should it be this.getValue1().view_count ? If the intent is to invoke a method, then you want to use the parentheses. It appears to work because in javascript a function is an object with fields, and it can't find any view_count field in that object.

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Point is that everything is async so it will not wait to get value 1 2 and 3 to make your last operation. You can use Rxjs ForkJoin otherwise. http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using a **promise**  it will help you because it isn't an *asynchronous* function. that's mean that you code will wait until finish the http response.

```
this._http.get('API URL').map(res => res.json()).toPromise()
```

Comment: I'm using Observable, i updated my post. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can make your funcs async to await some data

```
async getValue1() {
    result = await myAsyncOperation();
    return result;
}
```

but in angular there is rxjs to handle async operations so you should use observables...

JUST saw. you wrote getValue1 without btackets...

Comment: Sorry i failed when i post it. Is not working for me when i use async / await. Thanks for your help